# Why a char default value is not displayed on console?

Tags: java

I wanted to know what will it get displayed on console when you try to print a `char` default value. But unfortunately, I can't see anything on the console. why? 
I should be able to see `0` right. As the default value of a char variable is a null character i.e., `'\u0000'` (Its decimal equivalent is `0`) ? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Code:

```
public class Index {
    static char c;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("char default value is: "+Index.c);
    }
}
```

Output console:

[image]

Comment: If you had written `static char c = 65;`, would you expect it to have printed `65` or `A`?

Comment: you could print by referencing `c` instead of `Index.c` since you are calling from a static method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a big difference between the character for "the decimal digit 0" which is [U+0030](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0030/index.htm)... and [U+0000](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm), the null character, which is a control character and so has no printed output. You're printing out the latter, so I wouldn't expect to see 0.

To think about it another way, consider:

```
System.out.println("a\u0009b");
```

Would you expect that to print "a9b"? You shouldn't because U+0008 is the tab character, so you'd see something like "a b" with some variable number of spaces between depending on exactly what your output device does.

Answer (score 4):

Long time ago, when I was young, there was a thing called [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).
At that time there were only 128 different numerical representation of a character such as 'a' or '@' or an action of some sort to be done in the terminal.

But even at that time the '0' character had the decimal value 48.

Now the things are a little bit changed, now we have Unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.

But the story is not changed very much, for each character there is a code which represent the character in the given encoding.

As you probably already understood the '\u0000' is not the character `0`.

Take a look at [UTF-8 table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) to see which character is which code.

```
char zero = '0';
System.out.println(String.format("%d", (int)zero));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X", (int)zero));
```

**Update**

A little update to this post kindly suggested by @TomBlodget

We should also mention [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) common european encoding. Which was able to encode *àäöòåèéüù* and other characters with only one byte, the first 127 characters being the same as in US-ASCII (as often is, for convenience reasons).

And how forget the famous [OEM437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) codepage? This character set remained for long long time the primary font in the core of any EGA and VGA-compatible graphics card.

I would add also that the very common UTF-8 encoding also contains the US-ASCII charset, but it will encode the characters as two bytes.

Comment: Your post helped me in the other way!!

Comment: Not sure I got what do you mean... :) But anyway I'm happy you figure out

Comment: said that, I figured out through the ASCII table which you posted. @freedev

Comment: @freedev You could at least link to a web page that shows ISO 8859-1 instead of some other "extended ASCII". If you are going to talk about a character set that _Java's text datatypes don't use,_ at least ISO 8859-1 is a subset. (Besides, are you sure you weren't using something like OEM437 when you were studying ASCII?)

Comment: @TomBlodget Right. I wrote a little addendum to the post :) ...and changed all the links to wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

The default value for `char` is `\u0000`. You would not see zero even though the decimal equivalent is 0, just like doing the following will print `A` instead of `65`.

```
static char c = 65;
System.out.println(c);
```

For your code if you do `System.out.println(c==0);` it will return `true`, since they are equivalent like you mentioned.